# $\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{x^n}{n{2n\choose n}}=2\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Context: this is a purely recreational problem that I came up with myself.

I am trying to extend this colsed form:

$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^n}{n{2n\choose n}}=2\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}},\qquad 0<x<4$$
I know that $S(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^n}{n{2n\choose n}}$ [converges for $|x|<4$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxpb6ts7rb), but the closed form above only works for half that range. Is there a closed form for the other half?

I think that it might come down to figuring out how to integrate $$\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{xt^2-xt+1}$$
when $-4<x<0$, but I'm not sure. In your answer, please show your proof. Thanks.

---

For those interested, a proof.

Noting that ${2n\choose n}^{-1}=\frac{n\Gamma^2(n)}{2\Gamma(2n)}$,
$$S(x)=\frac12\sum_{n\geq1}\int_0^1x^n[t(1-t)]^{n-1}\mathrm dt$$
Then using the geometric series,
$$S(x)=\frac{x}2\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{xt^2-xt+1}$$
Then we focus on $$I(k;a,b,c)=\int_0^k\frac{\mathrm dt}{at^2+bt+c}$$
If we complete the square in the denominator then preform the appropriate trig substitution, we see that for $4ac>b^2$,
$$I(k;a,b,c)=\frac2{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\bigg[\arctan\frac{2ak+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}-\arctan\frac{b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\bigg]$$
So for $0<x<4$,
$$S(x)=\frac{x}2I(1;x,-x,1)$$
$$S(x)=2\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}$$
As desired.

Comment: $-i\arctan(ix)=\text{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ allows to cover the whole $(-4,4)$.

Comment: You are actually just integrating the Maclaurin series of the squared arcsine.

Comment: The integral you asked for equals $\frac{4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-4}}\right)}{\sqrt{(x-4) x}}$

Comment: @ablmf how do you find this?

Comment: @clathratus Mathematica. BTW, the anti-derivative is $\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{(2 t-1) \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}\right)}{\sqrt{-(x-4) x}}$. So this is the proof.